# Switching testers in specs tests

Tags: origen-sdk

I’ve been having a lot of trouble trying to figure out how to use the V93K for spec testing. For the J750 it was easy, I just did this:

```rb
  before(:context) do
    Origen.environment.temporary = 'j750.rb'
    Origen.load_target('default')

    c = Class.new do
      include OrigenTesters::ProgramGenerators
      include TIPShared::Interfaces::AnalogTestBase

      def func(name, options={})
        @current_test_config = test_instances.functional(name, options)
        @current_test_config
      end

      def t
        @current_test_config
      end
    end
    @test_interface = c.new
  end
```

Then  I could call @test_interface.func and do whatever with it.

Trying something similar with the 93K, I’m having all sorts of problems, the latest of which makes no sense as its still looking for IGXL stuff. So far what I have is:

```rb
  before(:context) do
    Origen.environment.temporary = 'v93k.rb'
    Origen.load_target('default')
    Origen.app.load_target!

    @c = Class.new do
      include OrigenTesters::ProgramGenerators
      include OrigenTesters::SmartestBasedTester
      #include OrigenTesters::SmartestBasedTester::V93K
      #include OrigenTesters::SmartestBasedTester::Base
      include TIPShared::Interfaces::AnalogTestBase

      def func(name, options={})
        @current_test_config = test_suites.add(name, options)
        @current_test_config.test_method = test_methods.origen.functional_test
        @current_test_config
      end

      def t
        @current_test_config
      end
    end
    @test_interface = @c.new

    Origen.file_handler.current_file = Pathname.new("#{Origen.app.root}/temp.rb")
  end
```

But trying @test_interface.func just gives:

Which is very confusing to me because I thought OrigenTesters::ProgramGenerators would pick the V93K instead. I can’t figure out if this is a problem/shortcoming of testers or if this is specs. I thought specs would basically ‘restart’ the application in the next context, so IGXL anything shouldn’t be loaded.

```
 Failure/Error: @current_test_config = test_suites.add(name, options)

 NameError:
   uninitialized constant OrigenTesters::IGXLBasedTester::J750::TestSuite
   Did you mean?  OrigenTesters::IGXLBasedTester::J750::TestInstance
 # /proj/.tec_k3s/users/cengelken_b50956/tr_origen/gems/ruby/2.3.0/gems/origen_testers-0.10.0/lib/origen_testers/smartest_based_tester/base/test_suites.rb:21:in `add'
 # ./spec/analog_test_base_spec.rb:262:in `func'
 # ./spec/analog_test_base_spec.rb:281:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./config/commands.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
 # /proj/.tec_k3s/users/cengelken_b50956/tr_origen/gems/ruby/2.3.0/gems/origen-0.24.0/lib/origen/commands.rb:183:in `require'
 # /proj/.tec_k3s/users/cengelken_b50956/tr_origen/gems/ruby/2.3.0/gems/origen-0.24.0/lib/origen/commands.rb:183:in `<top (required)>'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Corey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, @ginty. That did end up being the problem. I had previously messed with the interface by just clearing them and adding them back but it wasn't actually setting Origen.interface.

I managed to get this to work. Its not the prettiest, but seems to be working. To switch from J750 to 93K I did:

```
# Create a dummy file for the V93K interface to use. Doesn't need to exists, it won't actually be used, just needs to be set.
Origen.file_handler.current_file = Pathname.new("#{Origen.app.root}/temp.rb")

# Load V93K environment and reload the target.
Origen.environment.temporary = 'v93k.rb'
Origen.load_target('default')

# Clear the existing interface and reset Origen's current interface.
# ASIDE: this must be done after setting the current tester.
Origen.interfaces.clear
Origen.reset_interface
```

This is actually clearing the interface and setting it to 'NoInterface', but seems to be working all the same, at least for Specs testing purposes. Not sure if this will be a problem when I start actually generating sheets, but we'll find out.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if the way the class is being defined here is causing the assignment of the platform-specific API not to occur, see here: https://github.com/Origen-SDK/origen_testers/blob/master/lib/origen_testers/program_generators.rb#L23

You might try calling `c._load_generator` manually to see if that helps.

Alternatively, include the generators explicitly: `include OrigenTesters::V93K::Generator`

Could your `TIPShared::Interfaces::AnalogTestBase` module be including the Teradyne generators?

EDIT:

After further discussion it appears that the problem is that the new interface being created is not being assigned to `Origen.interface`.

There is an existing example of how to deal with multiple interface creation in a test situation here: https://github.com/Origen-SDK/origen_testers/blob/master/spec/interface_spec.rb#L22

Comment: I tried all three of those but to no avail. I even tried inheriting from OrigenTesters::SmartestBasedTester::V93K but that didn't do any good either. It seems that since its a module, its only loaded once, and since its loaded it won't be reevaluated when the tester changes or if a new interface includes it. I checked that if I remove all my J750 tests it works.

In any case, RSpec isn't 'reloading' everything like I thought it was. I undefined the module myself but now active concern is complaining that the module was included more than once. It looks like we need a way of reloading.

Comment: I think I see the problem, you may be creating a new interface object, but it is not being assigned to Origen.interface, which means that paths like these refer to the first interface you created: https://github.com/Origen-SDK/origen_testers/blob/master/lib/origen_testers/smartest_based_tester/base/test_suites.rb#L31

Comment: Yes, I've done this as well. I've cleared the interfaces, let program generators add it back, and added it manually. Same result. It seems to be that the interface  module itself isn't updated when the tester changes too.